# What is maximum application memory cap for Lumia 950?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-950

I know Windows Phone imposes restrictions on maximum memory each app can use. For lower memory devices (i.e. 512 MB devices) this seems to be about 180 MB and for higher memory devices i.e. 1 GB devices, this appears to be about 380 MB (According to [this answer to an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334530/how-to-get-the-amount-of-ram-512-mb-1gb-2gb-of-the-device-in-windows-phone-8/26257570#26257570)).
That being said ,what is higher app memory limit for the new device Lumia 950 that comes with 3 GB of RAM?

Comment: If you have a Lumia 950 you can find this info on apps like AIDA64, system information, etc...

Comment: I ran AIDA64 on my Lumia 950, and under Windows -> App Memory Usage Limit it says 1536 MB. Not sure if this is per app or total, but it's the best I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Indrek](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/1401/indrek) said in his comments, **the Application Memory cap is 1536MB.** This has been observed using an app called AIDA64. Since there is no reference to the limit on devices with more than 2GB of RAM we must take the practical result.

---

You can also refer to this Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx) which lists app memory limit as,

- 185MB for Lower memory devices,
- 390MB for 1GB phones,
- 825MB for 2GB phones.

These limits corresponds to Windows Runtime apps and not 8.0 based apps. For a more clear picture see the following image.

[image]

---

**Reference**

1. [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx)